# Почему не работает else?

Tags: javascript, form, форма, калькулятор

Пишу код для калькулятора на Webflow. Калькулятор простенький, но я в JS нулевый :( и не могу адаптировать пример под свой вариант.

**В чем суть:**

На входе дается `input` в который человек вводит число. В зависимости от того, какое число ввел человек будет совершаться умножение на заданные числа.
На выходе, должно вывести готовый результат.

К примеру, если человек вводит число Х (в диапазоне от 1 до 30), то нужно совершить действие x * 0 и вывести результат. Если вводит число Х (в диапазоне от 31 до 1000) то нужно совершить действие x * 0.23 и так далее.

Для примера скрин, как выглядит форма визуально:
[image: форма на webflow]

Из скрина понятно, что введенное число нужно перемножить на цену за эмейл, в зависимости от диапазона введенного числа.

В лучшем случае работает только первая часть с IF, в худшем вообще ничего не выводит :( Прошу помощи. Спасибо.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("invest_input");
if (input.value <= 30) {
  input.oninput = function() {
    var out = (input.value * 0);
  }
} else if (input.value <= 31 <= 1000) {
  input.oninput = function() {
    var out = (input.value * 0.03);
  }
} else if (input.value <= 1001 <= 5000) {
  input.oninput = function() {
    var out = (input.value * 0.028);
  }
} else if (input.value <= 5001 <= 10000) {
  input.oninput = function() {
    var out = (input.value * 0.025);
  }
} else if (iinput.value <= 10001 <= 100000) {
  input.oninput = function() {
    var out = (input.value * 0.020);
  }
} else {
  input.value <= 100001 <= 1000000
  input.oninput = function() {
    var out = (input.value * 0.015);
  }
  document.getElementById('invest_output_result').innerHTML = out.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="invest_input" value="123" />
```

Пример, который я попытался подогнать под себя:

```
<script>
        var input = document.getElementById("invest_input");
        input.oninput = function() {
        var out = ((input.value * 0.99) / 100) / 12;
            document.getElementById('invest_output_result').innerHTML = out.toFixed(2);
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Эту конструкцию Вы сами придумали? Что, интересно, она означает?

```
input.value <=31 <= 1000
```

---

```
var inputValue = +document.getElementById("invest_input").value;
...
else if (inputValue >= 31 && inputValue <= 1000) {
...
```

---

Это что делает?

```
input.oninput = function() {
  var out = (input.value * 0);
}
```

Comment: Здесь можно увидеть сам сайт где оно должно работать:
[https://scrubby-site.webflow.io/pricing-calculator]